# Undefined variable o

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure in MySQL. Here's the body:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE _date_delivered datetime;
DECLARE _date_last_comment datetime;
DECLARE _buyer_id int;
DECLARE _date_finish_line datetime;

   SELECT o.date_delivered INTO _date_delivered,o.buyer_id INTO _buyer_id, h.date INTO 
       _date_las_comment, DATE_ADD( h.date, INTERVAL _hours HOUR ) 
       INTO _date_finish_line 
   FROM wpk9_kk_order o 
   LEFT JOIN 
       wpk9_kk_order_history h ON 
       o.order_id = h.order_id WHERE o.order_id = _order_id AND h.user_id = o.buyer_id 
   ORDER BY h.date DESC;

   select _date_delivered,_buyer_id, _date_last_comment, _date_finish_line;
END
```

But when I save it, I get this error:

> One or more errors have occured while processing your request:
>
> The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE getAutoFinishTimeRemaining(IN _order_id INT, IN _hours INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN DECLARE _date_delivered datetime; DECLARE _date_last_comment datetime; DECLARE _buyer_id int; DECLARE _date_finish_line datetime; SELECT o.date_delivered INTO _date_delivered, o.buyer_id INTO _buyer_id, h.date INTO _date_las_comment, DATE_ADD( h.date, INTERVAL _hours HOUR ) INTO _date_finish_line FROM wpk9_kk_order o LEFT JOIN wpk9_kk_order_history h ON o.order_id = h.order_id WHERE o.order_id = _order_id AND h.user_id = o.buyer_id ORDER BY h.date DESC; select _date_delivered,_buyer_id, _date_last_comment, _date_finish_line; END"

**MySQL said: #1327 - Undeclared variable: o**

Comment: The problem (invalid syntax) exists in your `FROM` statement: `FROM wpk9_kk_order o`.

Comment: Check your `_date_last_comment` column.You have a typo while writing `_date_last_comment ` column in select statement. You have written `_date_las_comment`  (It is clearly seen in error message too) .

Answer (score 0):

Check your `_date_last_comment` column.You have a typo while writing `_date_last_comment` column in select statement. You have written `_date_las_comment`  (It is clearly seen in error message too) .

Your procedure should be:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE _date_delivered datetime;
DECLARE _date_last_comment datetime;
DECLARE _buyer_id int;
DECLARE _date_finish_line datetime;

   SELECT o.date_delivered INTO _date_delivered,o.buyer_id INTO _buyer_id, h.date INTO 
       _date_last_comment, DATE_ADD( h.date, INTERVAL _hours HOUR ) 
       INTO _date_finish_line 
   FROM wpk9_kk_order o 
   LEFT JOIN 
       wpk9_kk_order_history h ON 
       o.order_id = h.order_id WHERE o.order_id = _order_id AND h.user_id = o.buyer_id 
   ORDER BY h.date DESC;

   select _date_delivered,_buyer_id, _date_last_comment, _date_finish_line;
END
```